# cx_Oracle CREATE TABLE AS returns ORA-01036: illegal variable name/number

Tags: python, sql, oracle, solaris, cx-oracle

I'm trying to CREATE TABLE AS using cx_Oracle on Python 2.4.6

The following code:

```
    query = '''CREATE TABLE TMP_STATS_1 AS
    select NUM from INF_CARD where IMPORT_DATE between
    to_date(:datepass || ' 00:00:00','dd/mm/yyyy hh24:mi:ss') and
    to_date(:datepass || ' 23:59:59','dd/mm/yyyy hh24:mi:ss')'''
    curs.execute(query, datepass=datep)
```

Returns: **cx_Oracle.DatabaseError: ORA-01036: illegal variable name/number**

Taking out the `CREATE TABLE TMP_STATS_1 AS` and leaving only the `SELECT` statement, works perfectly. Also, when using `CREATE TABLE AS` statement on SQLPLUS it runs correctly.

Is there any specific syntax for `CREATE TABLE AS` to be used in cx_Oracle? Tried to find examples for this, but none found so far.

Comment: Is datep a date or varchar? Just guessing you might be passing date, while query expects varchar in dd/mm/yyyy format, which is explicitly converted by to_date.

Comment: datep was tested with datetime.now().strftime('%d/%m/%Y') no luck

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are better off creating a procedure in Oracle that can create your table, and then call the procedure form Python:

```
create or replace procedure my_pro(p_table_name in varchar2, p_date_pass in date) as
 q1 varchar2(4000);
begin

 q1 := 'CREATE TABLE '|| p_table_name ||' AS
 select NUM from INF_CARD where IMPORT_DATE between
 trunc('||p_date_pass||') and trunc('||p_date_pass||') + 1 - (1/24/60/60)';

 EXECUTE IMMEDIATE q1;
end;
```

and then call the procedure from Python:

```
import cx_Oracle
con = cx_Oracle.connect('###YourPath###')
cur = con.cursor()
cur.callproc('my_pro', ('TMP_STATS_1', datep))
cur.close()
con.close()
```

Comment: The correct syntax for creating a procedure in ORACLE is:CREATE PROCEDURE my_pro(p_statement in varchar2) as
 q1 varchar2(4000);
begin

 q1 := p_statement;

 EXECUTE IMMEDIATE q1;
end;
/