# cx_Oracle CREATE TABLE AS with bind variables returns ORA-01036

Tags: oracle, python-2.7, cx-oracle

Having the same problem as asked here: [23422467](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23433467)

In my case -- on RHEL 7, using cx_Oracle 5.1.3, Oracle 12.1 instant client, python 2.7.

```
dts={'dt1':datetime.date(2015, 05, 26), 'dt2':datetime.date(2015, 05, 27)}
cursor.execute("SELECT * FROM testt WHERE tdate BETWEEN :dt1 AND :dt2", dts)
cursor.execute("CREATE TABLE subtest AS 
                SELECT * FROM testt WHERE tdate BETWEEN :dt1 AND :dt2", dts)
```

The first cursor.execute() returns an iterable, the second returns ORA-01036.

The answer provided for [23422467](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23433467) suggests the work-around of creating a procedure in Oracle and using cursor.callproc() to pass procedure params as bind variable values, however I don't have privs to create a procedure in the database I'm working on here.

Why doesn't this work?

Seems like my only option is to ditch bind variables in cx_Oracle and use dynamic modification of the DCL sql string in python, but thats ugly.

Other options?

Comment: Try to create table and then populate it

Comment: It seems that cx_Oracle 5.1 doesn't support create as select

Comment: A clarification -- cur.execute("create table test as select 'test' testcol from dual") works just fine, so "create as select" is supported, just not with bind variables. Your suggestion to create an empty table and then use insert with bind variables and truncate to clear works fine.  If you write it up as an answer, I will select it.  Thanks.